# How to set custom memory region in Keil Scatter Loading Description File

Tags: linker, stm32, scatter, keil, rom

so I have a question with regards to the custom Scatter file I am about to use.

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00002000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

The ROM storage is from `0x08000000 ~ 0x08008000`. Would it be possible to set take some space from it say e.g. `0x08007C00 ~ 0x08007FFF` and set it to be a Read and Write region? Let's take that range of memory address as "User Data"

I would be using the "User Data" region in my program as a segment where data can be written while my main program is running and when I power down and power on the device, I can load the data that was previously written to that segment.

I am using a loop and `HAL_Flash_Program` to write data to the starting memory address of `0x08007C00`. What are the changes I must make on the Scatter file and possibly on my C file to enable writing data to the specified memory region while my main program is running?

Thanks

*I am using `STM32F051` micro-controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use flash as RAM. It is Read Only Memory. It can only be written to using special routines which are very slow and must write whole pages (I think that is the case on this processor anyway). Also you cannot execute code from the same flash page when programming it (possibly not at all). The only reason to use flash as writable memory when running your application would be to store non-volatile data (there are better methods) or firmware updating.

Comment: Hello, what I want do at that particular memory region is to save (write) user settings as the main program runs certain functions and then to load (read) those settings again if the device restarts. I have also checked the Map file, `0x08005000 ~ 0x08007FFF` is not used...so I suppose I can use `0x08007C00` right? Haha, I am pretty new to this. But if you have alternative ways of doing the same thing then I am all ears, thanks!

Comment: Look at the Flash manual for the processor. I there are some ST app notes that will help you.